# Equivalent arrangements of arrows

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs, topological-graph-theory

Given $n$ arrows arranged so that every arrow starts from the base of one of the arrows and ends on the base of one of the arrows, what should be meant by that two such arrangements are essentially the same? E.g. how many essentially different arrangements exists for $n=2$?

The diagram below shows only a fragment of a complete arrangement.
[image]

An arrow could also start or end on its own base.
[image]
I regard all arrangements for $n=1$ to be equivalent.

---

I had the feeling that there was a canonical answer, but that I just couldn't see it. Thinking about it a little more I found:

> A morphism is a function between the arrows of two arrangements which
>   in the obvious way preserves the structure, and equivalence is
>   "isomorphic to".

---

The accepted answer:
[image]
a={ <1,1,1> <2,1,1>} 
b={ <1,1,1> <2,1,2>} 
c={ <1,1,1> <2,2,1>} 
d={ <1,1,1> <2,2,2>}
e={ <1,1,2> <2,1,1>} 
f={ <1,1,2> <2,1,2>} 
g={ <1,1,2> <2,2,1>} 
h={ <1,2,1> <2,1,1>}
i={ <1,2,1> <2,1,2>}

Obviously this nine arrangements are non isomorphic due to definition.

Comment: Is your picture $n=2$ or $n=3$? And only one of the arrows starts or ends on another arrow in the picture.

Comment: So the puzzle is to try and guess what your definition of "equivalent arrangements" is?

Comment: Suppose $n=2$ and each of the two arrows starts and ends on itself. So, each arrow divides the plane into three regions, two of them bounded. Now, one of the arrows may be "inside" the other (contained in one of its bounded regions) or the two arrows may be separated. Are these equivalent or inequivalent arrangements?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you would tell us what this is *for*? What's the motivation? What are you trying to model?

Comment: @bof: yes, the definition should be "topological".

Comment: But the figures you drew for $n=1$ don't all look topologically equivalent.

Comment: Further to my answer below you can calculate how many arrangements there are by $ \frac{n^{2n}}{n!} + f(n) $ where $f$ returns the number of fixed points the permutation has.

Comment: @QthePlatypus: Thanks! why not edit your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each arrangement of arrows can be represented as a set of triples $ < name, head, tail> $ selected from an alphabet $\Sigma$ with the restriction that each triple has a unique name. In this representation $ \{ <0,0,0> \} $ would be your $ n = 1 $ case where an arrow starts and ends on its own base.

We then can define two arrangements to be equivalent if there is a permutation $ \Sigma \to \Sigma $ remaps one arrangement to the other.

With this definition I was able to iterate 9 examples for n=2.

{ <1,1,1> <2,1,1>}
{ <1,1,1> <2,1,2>}
{ <1,1,1> <2,2,1>}
{ <1,1,1> <2,2,2>}
{ <1,1,2> <2,1,1>}
{ <1,1,2> <2,1,2>}
{ <1,1,2> <2,2,1>}
{ <1,2,1> <2,1,1>}
{ <1,2,1> <2,1,2>}

Comment: Which are the nine arrangements for $n=2$?